# Issue with facebook in Sharekit

Tags: objective-c, sharekit

I've an issue with Facebook service on Sharekit.
I create an app in Facebook developers, and I insert App ID in SHKConfig.h file and the secret key, I left empty the third line about proxy, is this correct?

I can login, then a box appears to insert a message from the app that I've created in facebook, but when I click "Send" ShareKit gets closed and nothing happens, where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by sharekit gets closed?

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues in the last 24 hours about ShareKit. 
See here for more info and work-arounds

https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/234